# Pie chart with percentage in color filling

Tags: php, jquery, apache-flex

Sample Image url : http://173.201.63.11/CEOontheGO/chartsample

Is there any jquery component to draw the pie chart shown in the attached image? My requirement is if the pie chart has 6 segments, each segment color i have to fill based on the  percentage. if 100% is the input then that segment have to fill fully. if 50% is the input then half of the section of that segment have to fill the color.

Comment: Have you tried Google search: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20chart